# how to make custom domains

Tags: dns

How to make custom domains like  these

http://fb.me
http://youtu.be

Answer (score 3):

You buy them from registrars based in Montenegro and Belgium respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Domain name "youtu.be" is already owned by Google.
Domain name "fb.me" belongs to facebook.com

You can check if domain name is already registered for example here: http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Well, just register the domain name you want (something short probably).

If you want a URL shortener (as the http://youtu.be example) you will need to point this domain to a web application that will convert the short form to the original URL. You can download and install a small webapp (e.g. [shortenr](http://github.com/njacobeus/shortenr)) that does, need need to write one yourself.